# Right Join in Linq, not returning correct values

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to build this linq query and I'm having issues

I have two lists

ROOMS, which contains 
Id, Name, RoomStatus, OrderStatus, ConsructionType

STRINGMAP, which contains
AttributeName, AttributeValue, Value

```
var stringMap = from sm in _CRMcontext.StringMaps
                where sm.ObjectTypeCode == 10001 
                && sm.AttributeName == "new_status" 
                || sm.AttributeName == "new_projecttype" 
                || sm.AttributeName == "new_orderstatus" 
                || sm.AttributeName == "new_construction_type" 
                || sm.AttributeName == "new_stage"
                select sm;

var result = from set in ROOMS
             join roomStatus in stringMap on set.Status equals status.AttributeValue
             where roomStatus.AttributeName == "new_status"
             join orderStatus in stringMap on set.OrderStatus equals orderStatus.AttributeValue
             where orderStatus.AttributeName == "new_orderstatus"
             join consructionType in stringMap on set.ConstructionType equals consructionType.AttributeValue
             where consructionType.AttributeName == "new_construction_type"
             select new DTO.Shared.Project() {
                 Id = set.Id,
                 Name = set.Name,
                 RoomStatus = roomStatus.Value,                 
                 OrderStatus = orderStatus.Value,
                 ConstructionType = constructionType.Value,
                 };
```

So I'm only getting back results that don't have nulls in the join, I would like to get them back regardless of the null, similar to a right join in sql

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Could you provide a minimal set of example data which demonstrates the problem? For one thing, it looks like you need parenthesis around the sm.AttributeNames you are or-ing ('||') with in the first select.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an IQueryable implementation for a Right Outer Join:

```
private static Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>> CastSMBody<TP, TC, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TP unusedP, TC unusedC, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>>)ex;

public static IQueryable<TResult> RightOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    var sampleAnonLR = new { leftg = (IEnumerable<TLeft>)null, right = (TRight)null };
    var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "p");
    var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLeft), "c");
    var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "right");
    var newrightrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, parmC, argRight), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, (TLeft)null, (TResult)null);

    return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right }).SelectMany(l => l.leftg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newrightrs);
}
```

You can use it something like:

```
var result = ROOMS.RightOuterJoin(stringMap, set => new { set.Status, AttributeName = "new_status" }, roomStatus => new { Status = roomStatus.AttributeValue, roomStatus.AttributeName }, (set, roomStatus) => new { set.Id, set.Name, roomStatus.Value });
```